# strtok function not splitting at the given delimiter

Tags: c, string, strtok

Strtok is called like this:

`char *headers = strtok(NULL, "\n\n");`

on this string:

```
"Host: 172.27.34.56\nConnection: keep-alive\nDNT: 1\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7\ncp-extension-installed: Yes\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\nAccept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\nRange: bytes=85-85\nIf-Range: Wed, 19 Jul 2023 19:15:56 GMT\n\n123"
```

but it splits on the first `\n` instead of `\n\n`.
why?

Comment: That's by design.  `std::strtok` considers a single character to be a delimiter.  The second parameter is "all the different characters that could be a delimiter".

Comment: If you want to split on `"\n\n"`, consider using `strstr()` to find it — or a C++ equivalent (since `strstr()` is a C function, like `strtok()` is a C function).

Comment: You only need to specify *one* newline in the delimiter string passed to `strtok()`. This `"\n"` is enough to filter multiple occcurrences of `\n`. The second `\n` is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::strtok` takes a list of delimiting characters as its second argument. It doesn't split by a string/substring.

Cf. [The example on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok)

If you're not against using `std::string`, you can make a `tokUntil` function as follows:

```
std::string tokUntil(std::string str, std::string delimiter) {
  auto pos = str.find(delimiter);
  return pos === std::string::npos ? str : str.substr(0, pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comments and other answers, `strtok()` searches for *any* **single** instance of the characters listed in the second parameter.

**Given the sample string**, it appears you want to isolate the last field (following the double `'\n'`).

Try:

```
    char *fldPtr = strrchr( headers, '\n' );
    if( fldPtr ) fldPtr += 1; // advance past that newline.
```

This will hunt from the end of the string toward the beginning.

Depending on the consistency of the source data format, you may want to add validation that this is giving what you expect. For instance:

```
    char *fldPtr = strrchr( headers, '\n' );
    if( fldPtr ) {
        if( fldPtr != headers && fldPtr[-1] == '\n' ) // got "\n\n" ???
            fldPtr += 1; // advance past that newline.
        else
            fldPtr = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Only if the double-newline happens to be the last occurrence of a newline. This answer fails if the double-newline is not the last occurrence.

Comment: @WeatherVane While you've got a point, "Given the sample string, it appears you want..." Who's to say what form the OP's sample data may take? I'll bold the caveat to make it stand out... Cheers!

Comment: Exactly: who's to say what form the data may take. Jonathan Leffler pointed the way.